# Location of log file from Log4j2

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, log4j2, tomcat8

I am trying to setup up Log4j2 for a Java web app project using Jersey. This is my `log4j2.xml` file that is saved in `WEB-INF/classes`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="/home/hans/Dev/Software/Tomcat/logs/all.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I run the project on Tomcat in Intellij (IJ) it prints out fine to the console as per the `Log4j2.xml` file. When I deploy the same WAR file directly to a local Tomcat server  I can't get a console output and therefore I have specified a log file to be written to `/home/hans/Dev/Software/Tomcat/logs/all.log`. I've set the permission on the logs folder so that anyone can write to it but the log file isn't written to that folder.

At start up of the server in IJ I have the following message:

```
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: /WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: /WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

I've tried two different setups. Both giving the same error. These are teh two setups and result:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[image]

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

With `log4j2.xml` in `/WEB-INF/classes`
[image]

With `log4j2.xml` in `/WEB-INF`
[image]

Output from Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE. I can only see that it is looking for the configuration file but I can't see where it is looking.

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Log4jServletContainerInitializer starting up Log4j in Servlet 3.0+ environment.
DEBUG StatusLogger Loaded Provider Provider[priority=10, className=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory, url=jar:file:/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java%20Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.7.jar!/META-INF/log4j-provider.properties, classLoader=ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
]
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
DEBUG StatusLogger Using the servlet context name "CurrencyRegistry".
DEBUG StatusLogger getConfigURI found [log4j2.xml] in servletContext at [log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.087752 seconds to load 192 plugins from ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a

DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 4 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Json support
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@7dea68f1
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: log4j2.xml
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: log4j2.xml
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-testCurrencyRegistry.properties] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
.

<---MORE OF THESE TESTS TO FIND THE CONFIG FILE NONE OF THEM FINDS THE FILE--->

TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

After moving the `log4j2.xml` file into the `src` folder it now gets picked up by log4j2. I still get some warnings.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jose4j.jwa.AlgorithmFactoryFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I'm using Bitbuckets JWT library that uses SLF4J for logging and it needs to be bridged to log4j2 using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

After moving the file the output from  Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE is per below. Now it look like it is able to locate the file in `/WEB-INF/classes` even thought the file is under `src`. I don't know why.

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Log4jServletContainerInitializer starting up Log4j in Servlet 3.0+ environment.
DEBUG StatusLogger Loaded Provider Provider[priority=10, className=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory, url=jar:file:/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java%20Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.7.jar!/META-INF/log4j-provider.properties, classLoader=ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
]
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
DEBUG StatusLogger Using the servlet context name "CurrencyRegistry".
DEBUG StatusLogger getConfigURI found [log4j2.xml] in servletContext at [log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.097889 seconds to load 192 plugins from ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a

DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 4 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Json support
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@2f824a06
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@4629104a
.
2017-01-18 11:01:06,589 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Starting LoggerContext[name=CurrencyRegistry] from configuration at log4j2.xml
2017-01-18 11:01:06,590 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Starting LoggerContext[name=CurrencyRegistry, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@77feb3ee] with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml]...
2017-01-18 11:01:06,596 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2017-01-18 11:01:06,598 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml]
2017-01-18 11:01:06,610 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Installed script engines
2017-01-18 11:01:07,234 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_111, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2017-01-18 11:01:07,235 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 108 plugins
2017-01-18 11:01:07,235 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2017-01-18 11:01:07,241 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Log4j2 ConfigurationScheduler: No scheduled items
2017-01-18 11:01:07,242 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 14 plugins
2017-01-18 11:01:07,245 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,258 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,259 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
2017-01-18 11:01:07,281 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-01-18 11:01:07,282 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2017-01-18 11:01:07,283 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,296 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), name="Console", Filter=null)
2017-01-18 11:01:07,297 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2017-01-18 11:01:07,297 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,299 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-01-18 11:01:07,318 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,322 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG FileAppender$Builder(fileName="/home/mikael/Dev/Software/Tomcat/logs/all.log", append="null", locking="null", advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", Configuration(/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml), bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), name="MyFile", Filter=null)
2017-01-18 11:01:07,326 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Starting FileManager /home/mikael/Dev/Software/Tomcat/logs/all.log
2017-01-18 11:01:07,326 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,327 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG createAppenders(={Console, MyFile})
2017-01-18 11:01:07,328 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,333 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-01-18 11:01:07,334 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,334 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="MyFile", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-01-18 11:01:07,335 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,337 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={Console, MyFile}, ={}, Configuration(/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-01-18 11:01:07,342 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2017-01-18 11:01:07,343 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG createLoggers(={root})
2017-01-18 11:01:07,345 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml] initialized
2017-01-18 11:01:07,345 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml]
2017-01-18 11:01:07,346 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/home/mikael/Dev/Java/Java Programs/CurrencyRegistry/target/CurrencyRegistry/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml] OK.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,346 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@31af9852...
2017-01-18 11:01:07,346 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,347 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,347 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,348 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,348 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2017-01-18 11:01:07,348 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2017-01-18 11:01:07,349 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,349 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
2017-01-18 11:01:07,349 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@31af9852 OK
2017-01-18 11:01:07,352 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@3b475abf
2017-01-18 11:01:07,352 RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): 'CurrencyRegistry' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@77feb3ee
```

I don't know why it is not working when the configuration file is in the `WEB-INF` folder. Maybe is is something with my folder structure that doesn't work with how log4j2 locates the configuration file. I also don't understand why it finds the configuration file under `/WEB-INF/classes` when I moved it to `src`.

Comment: Try setting `<Configuration status="trace">` in the configuration to see if any errors occur during Log4j2 initialization.

Comment: Trace gave some more output to the console. The issue seems to be that log4j2 not being able to find the log4j2.xml file. I can't understand why it can't find it. I've added some more info regarding my folder structure and the configuration in the web.xml file.

Comment: So much has been tried, its hard to follow what the combinations of factors are. This seems to be a mavenized project, the only thing necessary should be to put the file in `src/main/resources`, which will trigger the maven war plugin to package it inside `WEB-INF/classes`. No further configuration should be necessary, log4j by convention will look for the configuration file in the root of the classpath, which includes WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: hope this helps someone, `spring` default not using `log4j2` [from the tutorial.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#log4j2-configuration-logging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the specified path is relative to the root of the web application classpath, so this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

will only be found if `WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml` exists. Since in your example the `log4j2.xml` file is in the root of the classpath, the below configuration should be sufficient:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

You can [debug](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting) the configuration by setting system property `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE`.

---

The `log4j:WARN` messages are not generated by Log4j2. You only see these messages when there is an old Log4j 1.2.x jar file in the classpath somewhere.

---

IntelliJ copies all resources in `src` to the classpath (WEB-INF/classes). During a build it probably cleans the target directory first so it deleted any files that you manually copied there. So don't manually put files in `classes`, you're just fighting the IDE at that point. The standard setup is to follow the Maven directory layout, which is to put the configuration file in a `resources` directory. This directory needs to be added to the classpath. See the IntelliJ help for designating folders as resource folders.

Comment: I gave that a try both with the `log4j2.xml` file in the `/WEB-INF` folder and `/WEB-INF/classes` folder. But it still can't find it. Should I move the `log4j2.xml` file somewhere else?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I guess putting `log4j2.xml` in the `src` folder is the solution for IJ. 
`log4j:WARN` was caused by wrong bridging dependency. I was using `slf4j-log4j12` version 1.7.22. Changing to `log4j-slf4j-impl` version 2.0.2 solved the issue.